# Can't Create a New Folder in Home

Tags: themes, hidden-files, unity-tweak-tool

I'm trying to install a theme and another forum said to create a folder in my home directory and put the theme in there, then use Unity Tweak Tool to activate it. So, I created a folder in my home directory, called it `.theme`. However, when I returned to my home directory, my `.theme` directory was gone. So I thought: I'll just make a new folder. But when I tried to create a new folder called `.theme`, I get an error saying that the name is already in use and I cannot use `.theme`. But there is no folder in my home directory titled `.theme`.

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.

Comment: "dotfiles" are hidden by default: try hitting Ctrl-H in the filemanager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.theme` directory is hidden by default because of the `.` at the front of its name. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see all hidden directories (and files).

If you want to *permanently* see all hidden directories and files, open a Nautilus window and go to "Edit" -> "Preferences" and check the "Show hidden and backup files" box. Note that backup files are files that end with `~`.

Answer (score 3):

Folders that start with a dot are hidden by default. You'll need to enable "Show Hidden Files and Folders" in the view options menu of your file manager, or by pressing CTRL-H.